# Insert an Array Formula via VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I'm using VBA, and I need to insert an array formula (the one that if I'm writing it manually, I'll press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and not just <kbd>Enter</kbd>). When I'm inserting it like a regular formula it doesn't work, neither when I put it with {} around it...
What's the correct way of writing that formula using VBA?

The formula is this:

```
 =INDEX(subset!R1C1:R2472C10,MATCH(1,(RC1=subset!C1)*(RC2=subset!C2)*(RC5=subset!C5)*(RC6=subset!C6),0),10)
```

Comment: Assigning an array formula to a cell or range uses the `Range("A1").FormulaArray = "<the formula>"` syntax. It does not matter whether you have the formula in *xlA1* or *xlR1C1* format.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're looking for the `FormulaArray` property that you can set for a cell like so:

```
Range("A1").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(subset!R1C1:R2472C10,MATCH(1,(RC1=subset!C1)(RC2=subset!C2)(RC5=subset!C5)*(RC6=subset!C6),0),10)"
```

See the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837104%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Very good.  But how do you do it R1 C1 which is what I needed...

Answer (score 0):

`FormulaArray` unfortunately does not preserve relative cell referencing when applied to a range as expected with `FormulaR1C1`. To keep the cell referencing relative in a vertical range you can use `FillDown`.

First enter the Array Formula in the first row of the range:

```
Range("A1").FormulaArray = "=SUM((R1C5:R2C10 = ""INCLUDE"") * RC5:RC10)
```

Then Fill Down the desired range:

```
Range("A1:A10").FillDown
```