# excel To return the Header from the last number that >100 in a row

Tags: excel-formula

I wish to To return the Header from the last number in row B that >100 , but currently I only manage to get the first number that >100 which is "july", But the answer that I want is "Aug" please help...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This array formula (ctrl+shift+enter !) should do the trick:
`{=INDEX($P$1:$AA$1,MAX(IF(P2:AA2>100,COLUMN(P2:AA2)-COLUMN(INDEX(P2:AA2,1,1))+1)))}`

The way this works is the following (and you can follow this if you select a part in the formula bar in Excel and type F9 to see the intermediate result) :

- `COLUMN(P2:AA2)-COLUMN(INDEX(P2:AA2;1;1))+1` creates a very simple array withe the column numbers of your range `result={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}`
- The `P2:AA2>100` also creates an array with TRUE/FALSE when the condition is met `result={FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}`
- The `IF` combines both : `result={FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,7,8,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}`
- With the `MAX` you select the largest value, which will be `8` in our case
- And with the `INDEX` you get then the 8th value of the range, which is `Aug`

So the trick is combining a matching condition with a simple sequential array with the same number of values as there are in your range.

Comment: Ok, I'll update my answer with some explanation (and please accept the answer if it is to your satisfaction ;))

Comment: possible coidng ctrl+shift+enter into vba?

Comment: I never use VBA, so I cannot help you with that.

Comment: @Issac_n For VBA, see this SO question and accepted answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604084/insert-an-array-formula-via-vba